# How to make FOR /F tokens work more universal (path related)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, token

I have a situation here that is as followed:

I've extracted a registry value under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` with folder locations.

The problem is that the code works for a path that has a space in it, but if i use the very same code for a path that has no spaces in it, the output is wrong.

I know it is related to `tokens` but i'm hoping there is a way to make the code work for both cases .

The code i currently have looks as followed:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %I in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Startup ') DO echo "%J"
```

and the output:

```
"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

**On a side note**: expanding `%USERPROFILE%` is no problem for me, i simply use the `CALL` function for that

Now, when changing the path of registry value `Startup` to something that doesn't have any spaces in it, the before mentioned code fails.

Hopefully someone has a way to make it work in both cases.

With best regards,

**copyitright**

Comment: With what `something that doesn't have any spaces in it` does it `fail` (ie produce a result I don't expect) - what does it produce, and why is that incorrect

Comment: You're right, but i wasn't able to reproduce the problem at the time and it appears it's the registry "key" itself that affected the output, not the key "value" (MC ND hits the spot!)

Comment: `reg.exe` seems to use four consecutive spaces to separate value names, data types and values from each other; so, given that the value does never contain such four spaces on its own, what about replacing those four spaces by a character that does never occur in the value either, then using this character as the delimiter?

Comment: Hm, I didn't even know that was the case. Let alone how to achieve this. But it appears someone has found the solution i'm looking for (Aacini, below).  Don't get me wrong though, i appreciate EVERY single (alternative) solution someone comes up with. Each solution has its pros and cons anyway. So thank you for bringing this up :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution does not "make FOR /F tokens more universal", but get the value placed after `"REG_EXPAND_SZ    "` string instead that, IMHO, is what you want...

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Startup') do set "value=%%a"
set "value=%value:*REG_EXPAND_SZ    =%"
echo "%value%"
```

Comment: I believe we have our winner here boys and girls. @Aacini: Before i decided to ask my question on stackoverflow, i actually was thinking of a way to replace the value string with the aid of DosTips.com, and leave out the irrelevant information. I failed, but YOUR example works a treat! THIS is the solution i was looking for and i thank you with much gratefulness for sharing this knowledge with me :-)

Answer (score 5):

One of the requirements of the `for /f` command usage is the correct use (when needed) of `delims` and `tokens` clauses. They have to be properly adapted to the format of the line(s) being processed.

Your problem here is that the output of the `reg.exe` command does not include a clear, unmistakable delimiter. We usually use the default space/tab delimiters to process the `reg.exe` output but as you have found, sometimes the general format has to been adapted to process different lines as

```
Cache    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
My Pictures    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\Pictures
```

In the second line the additional space present in the value name requires a different `tokens` clause when using space as delimiter.

And no, there is not any *universal* way of dealing with the output of the `reg.exe` command. You need to *know* what you request and *adapt* to it.

An alternative, if you *know* your value names will not include a underscore is to use it as a delimiter. This will split the line in the `REG_*` value type, leaving a token that can be splitted using the space as a delimiter

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a in ('
        reg query 
            "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" 
            /v "My Pictures"
    ') do for /f "tokens=1,*" %%c in ("%%b") do echo "%%d"
```

Another alternative is to use another way to retrieve the value. You can use `wmic` to query the registry. Something like (sorry, spanish locale)

```
W:\>wmic /NameSpace:\\root\default Class StdRegProv Call GetStringValue hDefKey="&H80000001" sSubKeyName="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" sValueName="My Pictures"
Ejecutando (StdRegProv)->GetStringValue()
Ejecución correcta del método.
Parámetros de salida:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 0;
        sValue = "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Pictures";
};
```

This output can be processed by retrieving the `sValue` line and using the quotes as delimiters (not the only way, just an example)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion    

    for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%a in ('
        WMIC /NameSpace:\\root\default Class StdRegProv 
            Call GetExpandedStringValue 
                hDefKey^="&H80000001" 
                sSubKeyName^="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" 
                sValueName^="My Pictures" 
        ^| find "sValue"
    ') do echo "%%~fa"
```

**note**: The `wmic` sample code uses the `Shell Folders` subkey instead of the `User Shell Folders` because the `wmic` was expanding `%userprofile%` to the `system` user profile folder and I'm not sure if this is a default/logic behaviour or it is a problem in my machine. When I have another machine at hand I will test it.

Comment: MC ND hits the spot!  If only i knew it on beforehand that it was the registry "key" that affected my output... I wasn't able to reproduce the problem until i noticed your post. I've marked your answer as the solution and on top of that u've made my day! :-)

Comment: On a side note: Does the output get affected if there are more than one spaces in the (to be) extracted path? Unfortunately i can't reproduce this the way i want because every change i make to "User Shell folders" require a restart.

Comment: 5+ minutes have passed, here's another attempt (english isn't my native/mother language)...    **On a side note**: Using FOR /F tokens/delims/skip solely, when the code works for a path that has one space, will the same code still work if someone decides to change the folder location to something that has more spaces in it? Unfortunately i can't reproduce this the way i want because every change i make to "User Shell folders" requires a restart.

Comment: @copyitright, a) If you are retrieving the data from the defined `*` token, you don't have problems. The problem are spaces creating additional tokens on the left that will move where the `*` starts to retrieve information. b) Instead of debugging using the `User Shell Folders`, try with another branch, ex. place your values under the `HKCU\Volatile Environment`

Comment: The `wmic` approach works fine for me, even with the `User Shell Folders` key (on Windows 10 x64)...

Comment: ...oops, now I got you, `%USERPROFILE%` is also expanded to the system profile folder on my machine; did you run your code as administrator?

Comment: @aschipfl, no, the user was member of the administrators group but code was executed in a non elevated console. It seems the variable expansion is done inside the OS in a layer with a different `%userprofile%` but I don't have at hand the required tools for testing.

Comment: @MC ND: Thanks for pointing this out. And silly of me to not think of trying a different registry location in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`reg.exe` uses four consecutive <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> to separate value names, data types and values from each other in the output (after an empty line and the line holding the key):

> ```cmd
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
>     Startup    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
> ```

So, given that the value does never contain such four <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> on its own, you could replace them by a character that does never occur in the value either, then use this one as the delimiter, e. g., the `|`:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // The `skip=2` option skips the empty line and the key from being iterated:
for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%R in ('
    reg query ^
        "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" ^
        /v "Startup"
') do (
    rem // Store line of interest in environment variable:
    set "LINE=%%R"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to not lose exclamation marks:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Replace `    ` by `|` and use the latter as the delimiter character;
    rem    token 1 is dismissed but is included for the loop to iterate even in case
    rem    the 3rd token, namely the value, was empty: */
    for /F "tokens=2,* delims=|" %%V in ("!LINE:    =|!") do (
        endlocal
        echo(%%W
    )
)
```

This approach fails in case the value name contains four consecutive <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> or the used delimiter character `|`.

---

Alternatively, you could search for the string 4 × <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `REG_`, because all registry data types begin with `REG_`; then from the string behind that, remove everything up to the next four consecutive <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> to extract the value:

```cmd
@echo off
rem /* The `eol=H` option skips the line with the key (`HKEY_*`) from being iterated;
rem    the empty line is skipped anyway by `for /F`: */
for /F "delims= eol=H" %%R in ('
    reg query ^
        "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" ^
        /v "Startup"
') do (
    rem // Store line of interest in environment variable:
    set "LINE=%%R"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to not lose exclamation marks:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Remove everything up to `    REG_`, so the value name is split off;
    rem    this works only because every value type begins with `REG_`: */
    set "LINE=!LINE:*    REG_=!"
    rem // Then remove everything up to `    `, so the actual value remains:
    echo(!LINE:*    =!
    endlocal
)
```

This approach fails in case the value name (not the value) contains four consecutive <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> followed by the string `REG_`.

---

Due to the fact that there are a very limited number of known registry data types, we could even search the line for these strings, preceded and followed by four <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>:

```cmd
@echo off
rem /* The `eol=H` option skips the line with the key (`HKEY_*`) from being iterated;
rem    the empty line is skipped anyway by `for /F`: */
for /F "delims= eol=H" %%R in ('
    reg query ^
        "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" ^
        /v "Startup"
') do (
    rem // Store line of interest in environment variable:
    set "LINE=%%R"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to not lose exclamation marks:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Loop through the possible registry value data types, search the line for
    rem    `    ` + a data type name + `    ` and remove everything up to that: */
    for %%T in (
        REG_SZ,REG_MULTI_SZ,REG_EXPAND_SZ,REG_DWORD,REG_QWORD,REG_BINARY,REG_NONE
    ) do (
        set "LINE=!LINE:*    %%T    =!"
    )
    echo(!LINE!
    endlocal
)
```

Since it is very unlikely that the search strings occur in the value name and the value itself, I consider this as the most reliable method when using the `reg` command.